# How to compare reactive objects using Pinia and Vue3?

Tags: vuejs3, pinia

This might seem trivial but I haven't been able to find a proper answer as to why comparing two objects stored in Pinia would fail.

store/dev.js

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useDevStore = defineStore('dev', {
  state: () => {
    return {
      character: null,
      skills: [],
    }
  }
});
```

view/dev.vue

```js
<script setup>
import { onBeforeMount } from 'vue';
import { useDevStore } from '@/stores/dev.js'

const devStore = useDevStore();

onBeforeMount(() => {
  devStore.character = {
    name: 'foo',
    skills: [
      {id: 1, name: 'a'},
    ],
  };

  devStore.skills = [
    {id: 1, name: 'a'},
    {id: 2, name: 'b'},
  ];

  const parsed = devStore.skills.filter(e => !devStore.character.skills.includes(e));

  console.log(parsed);
  // [{id: 1, name: 'a'}, {id: 2, name: 'b'}]
});
</script>
```

I haven't been able to filter the `devStore.skills` array for some reason and I can't really figure out why.

Any advice and link to specific point in Pinia's doc would be appreciated. I may be missing some reactivity concept but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare objects because they are a reference type. And in your example, these are different links. However, you can compare some unique properties to filter the objects you need. So to speak:

```
const parsed = devStore.skills.filter(item => 
   !devStore.character.skills.some(subItem => subItem.id === item.id));
```

your example in action:

```js
const useDevStore = Pinia.defineStore('dev', {
  state: () => {
    return {
      _character: {},
      _skills: [],
    }
  },
  getters: {
    character: (state) => state._character,
    skills: (state) => state._skills,
  },
  actions: {
    setCharacter(data) {
      this._character = data;
    },
    setSkills(data) {
      this._skills = data;
    },
  }
});

const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const devStore = useDevStore();

    Vue.onBeforeMount(() => {
      devStore.setCharacter({
        name: 'foo',
        skills: [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'a'
        }, ],
      });

      devStore.setSkills([{
          id: 1,
          name: 'a'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'b'
        },
      ]);

      const parsed = devStore.skills.filter(item => !devStore.character.skills.some(subItem => subItem.id === item.id))
      //(e => !devStore.character.skills.includes(e));

      console.log(parsed);
      // [{id: 1, name: 'a'}, {id: 2, name: 'b'}]
    });

  },
  template: `<div></div>`,
});

const pinia = Pinia.createPinia();
app.use(pinia);

app.mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-demi"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pinia"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```